# UNIX sockets: Is it possible to spoof getsockopt() SO_PEERCRED?

Tags: c, security, sockets, unix, unix-socket

Is there a (compatible) way to **spoof** (as root) the **unix socket** (file system sockets) **peer credentials** which can be obtained by [`getsockopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), option `SO_PEERCRED`?

*Background:*
I need to connect to a server application (which I cannot modify) which checks the `UID` of the process which connects to it via `SO_PEERCRED`. I'd like to spoof the information in order to be able **to connect** to the application **as root, too**.

**UPDATE**

*To clarify the question*:
I'm searching for a non-invasive way that the server sees a specific peer `UID`/`GID`.
Solutions are **discouraged** which need to alter the kernel (or take the use of kernel modules) or which **changes the server process** or its **loading/linking process** in any way (`LD_PRELOAD`, system call interceptions etc.).

Basically, the solution should work when running on any linux (or unix in general) server without any special requirements. The server process might already be running.

Comment: If you're `root`, why not just `setuid`? You could do that from a fully-controlled child process so you could avoid actually losing the privilege.

Comment: I'm not sure, but under Linux there is an octal value prefixed flags in `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo/<sd>`.

Comment: Can you control the starting of the server process, ie, can you use an LD_PRELOAD to modify the library function / syscall thunk to change the reported credentials?

Comment: @MRalwasser: What do you mean by "spoof"? Would running the server application on a different server with a modified kernel or with a hacked Glibc be considered "spoofing". How about using ``setuid``? Is that "spoofing"? Usually neither of these methods would be considered a "spoof".

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right lines. A root process has the privileges to spoof things like this, the problem is just that SO_PEERCRED provides no mechanism or API for a process to specify what identity should be to presented to the peer.

Two things you can do:

1. Temporarily drop root (`setreuid(desired,-1)`) when you make the `connect` call. A unix-domain connection is stamped with the credentials of the peer at the time the process called `connect` (and `listen` going the other way). SO_PEERCRED does not tell you the credentials of the peer at the current moment. Then you can resume root.
2. Better, use another API. The message-passing API lets a process pick what identify to present to a peer. Call `sendmsg` with a `struct cmsg` that contains the credentials you want to send. The kernel will ignore the credentials specified by an unprivileged user and always make sure the other side sees the actual identity, but a privileged process can pretend to be anyone else. This is a better match for your needs, because dropping and regaining root is a perilous activity and in this case unnecessary. Google for "SCM_CREDENTIALS" (or "man -K" for it on your system) to get code samples.

Comment: If the server does not set the SO_PASSCRED socket option and read the credentials then solution 2 won't work. If it only uses SO_PEERCRED then you are stuck with simple, one-shot PID authentication. For SO_PEERCRED example see http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/scm_cred_recv.c.html. In any event, for root to use SCM_CREDENTIALS to lower privilege is hardly "spoofing".

Comment: OK, call it "impersonating" then... Also, I seem to remember that if you send some credentials, you shouldn't need to set SO_PASSCRED on the other end; they should just arrive for you in the `recvmsg` output. Perhaps that's OS dependant? I don't tend to use linux. SO_PASSCRED is usually for when you want to read out credentials but the other side isn't writing them; it tells the kernel to give you the peer's credentials with each message (particularly nice for DGRAM sockets).

Comment: Read the example, "We must set the SO_PASSCRED socket option in order to receive credentials". Same is true for BSD/FreeBSD where the option is called SCM_CREDS.

Answer (score -1):

No. The reason is that the mechanism that provides the UID and GID of the peer is **internal to the kernel**, and you can't spoof the kernel! The kernel uses the PID of the peer to deduce the effective credentials of the peer. This happens when one side does a `connect` on the socket. See the call to `copy_peercred()` from `unix_stream_connect()` in `net/unix/af_unix.c`. There isn't any way that the peer can change the data it sends or the socket that will convince the kernel that the peer's PID isn't what it is. This is different from AF_INET sockets where the kernel has no internal knowledge of the peer's process and can only see the data in the IP packet headers that the peer sends.

The only thing that you can do to get this effect is to set the effective UID of the peer process to root or whatever UID/GID you want, and for that you need either root password or `sudo` privileges.

Comment: But you *can* spoof the kernel - as root, you can modify the behavior of the running kernel by loading a module.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: No module you write can change the behavior of Unix domain sockets.

Comment: You are **severely** mistaken to believe that.  The easiest approach would be craft a module which will re-direct the system call at the point of dispatch just after entry to the kernel, but modifying the internals of the unix domain socket implementation is ultimately an option too.  Remember, something that is not exported is not *protected*, it is merely *harder to locate* - and not all that that hard when the source is open and the build settings likely known.

Comment: Among other possibilities, yes.  But that article makes a deeply mistaken assumption in suggestion that the kernel must first be modified to export the sys call table.  That's not true - there are many known properties which allow it to be found.